# Run program when/instead of writing to FIFO?

Tags: pipe, fifo, mkfifo

I have a program that writes data every second to a FIFO. Now I want to alter some of this data and write it to another FIFO.

What would be the best approach? Can I somehow pipe this directly to my program (I have no control over/source code of the original program)? Or would I have to create a program that runs in the background and constantly polls the FIFO for new input?

Comment: What kind of FIFO do you mean? A named pipe? Something else? Can you control which named pipe this program uses? Can you control whatever reads from this named pipe?

Comment: Yes, a named pipe. Yes, I can control the name of the output pipe. Is there a way to pass the output of the first process directly to my program?

Comment: The usual way is just to make your program read the named pipe; the read will block when no data is available. Your program can output data in any way it likes; I'd suggest using `stdout` like all unix tools, so you can pipe it somewhere else, including to a name pipe. But of course you can also write directly to a different named pipe, it'll be less flexible this way, though.

Comment: Thx! What do you mean by "write directly to a different named pipe"?

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way is like this:

Example for your modifying program `yours.c` (doesn't do anything):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char argv[])
{
  char buf[1024];
  int n;

  do {
    n = fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), stdin);
    fwrite (buf, sizeof(char), n, stdout);
  } while (n > 0);
}
```

Setup for the original program:

```
mknod first.pipe
original_program first.pipe
```

Now run in a second terminal (or in the background)

```
yours < first.pipe | other_programs
```

Or, if you want to use a named pipe

```
mknod second.pipe
yours < first.pipe > second.pipe
other_prgrams < second.pipe
```

To repeat: In most cases you don't actually need a named pipe (fifo), using `|` in the shell works just fine. You also don't need to hardcode a specific pipe into your own programs, ust use redirection.

Comment: Can't use |  because the original output and input services rely on named pipes. I tried this code, but it aways stops after writing to second.pipe, if sth else is reading from second.pipe. Can I keep it "open" somehow?